# Username with special characters gets displaced in profile dashboard. Bug?

Tags: bug, design, profile-page

This happened for [this particular user.](https://anime.stackexchange.com/users/66771/%EA%A8%84-%E1%8F%92%C9%AA%E1%B4%9B%CF%83-%EA%AA%97%E1%B4%9C%E1%B4%9C%E1%B4%8B%C9%AA-%EA%A8%84)

[image]

I tested with [one more user who happens to be a mod but the name doesn't get displaced](https://anime.stackexchange.com/users/63/%D0%BA%D1%8F%CE%B1z%D1%94%D1%8F)

[image]

This happens in mobile browser only. Is it a bug?

Comment: Related report on [metase] concerning long usernames instead, but also observed on mobile: [Long usernames overlap with the Profiles/Network profile button on mobile](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/378753).

Comment: @Namaskaram I just did an experiment a bit and looks like it's the same issue: the wrapping is based on the length of the meta-info "Member for [...]", not considering the length of the username. I could reproduce this issue on incognito/logged-out, but not when logged in as a mod, since I'd also see "Visited [...]" on the meta-info, making it long enough to prevent a premature wrapping.

Comment: @AkiTanaka Oh, good to know! I noticed that you've commented on the post on Meta SE; maybe a link to this one would also help whoever is tasked with fixing this bug.